# Android Emulator Fails To Launch :: Failed to install apk on device 'emulator-5554': null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-indigo

This is the background of my setup.

Eclipse version Indigo. Windows 7

Since of two days I am failing to launch my applications on the emulator.
I get the below error on DDMS Console.

```
[2014-01-27 12:36:11 - NVProductManager] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-01-27 12:36:11 - NVProductManager] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-01-27 12:36:57 - NVProductManager] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-27 12:36:57 - NVProductManager] Uploading NVProductManager.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-27 12:37:07 - NVProductManager] Installing NVProductManager.apk...
[2014-01-27 12:39:19 - NVProductManager] Failed to install NVProductManager.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-01-27 12:39:19 - NVProductManager] (null)
[2014-01-27 12:40:19 - NVProductManager] Failed to install NVProductManager.apk on device 'emulator-5554': null
[2014-01-27 12:40:19 - NVProductManager] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
[2014-01-27 12:40:19 - NVProductManager] Launch canceled!
```

I have cleaned my projects, restarted eclipse and increased the ADB timeout to 60000,killed the adb.exe,tried setting a new device in AVD but still haven't found the culprit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing in mobile instead of AVD?

Comment: Hi, yup when i install the APK on the mobile it works. However, it is always troublesome to turn to the phone when I wanna check the code. That's why I'm insisting on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the emulator separately from AVD Manager, Then after its up and running and you were able to see the Home screen, at that time you can Run you application from Eclipse IDE, targeting to this specific Emulator.Your app will run smoothly.

Comment: It just gives me emulator-arm.exe has stopped working error message. Now it won't launch a single emulator. With or without any open projects. I downloaded the latest ADT which comes with eclipse. I get the same error message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Eclipse Luna on a Linux Virtual Machine for Android Development using Oracle Virtual Box.
I was facing issues when trying to run Projects on an Android Phone like described: Failed to install *apk.

**I solved it by setting "USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" on Android Virtual Box----> Virtual Machine --->Virtual Machine Configuration ----> USB.**

Prior to set USB 2.0 I had to install "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score -1):

Update the Android SDK Manager by windows->Android SDK Manager.
Then create new AVD Manager hope these will works

Comment: No the problem is not the SDK Manager release